# Where are doxycycline's anti-inflammatory properties derived from?

Tags: pharmacology, antibiotics, organic-chemistry

I have been looking at this antibiotic called doxycycline which is used mainly as an antibiotic. It has however some interesting anti-inflammatory properties. Does anyone know where these anti-inflammatory properties come from, chemically?

Comment: See [this page](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge) for information on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doxycyline inhibits iNOS and TNF-alpha expression.   It also influences secretion of IL-1beta, IL-8, and TNF-alpha, as well as other inflammatory cytokines.

[These are results collected from multiple systems.]

For appropriate references, see: [Leite et al (2011). Anti-inflammatory properties of Doxycycline and Minocycline in experimental models: an in vivo and in vitro comparative study. Inflammopharmocology.](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10787-011-0077-5/fulltext.html)

As for the chemistry of how doxycycline accomplishes these things, I'm afraid I don't know the answer, but hopefully, this gives you a place to start.